# CSS Properties won't render

Tags: css

my CSS properties won't render.  Fonts, widths etc. do nothing and I have no idea why.  I've tried multiple things.

I'd like to have a percentage width for the nav and the logo but all render 100% width.  It seems like I have a huge misunderstanding on how CSS works but after I read, I still don't get it.  I have normalize.css added in Wordpress too.

If I add and span class around the text, it will change the text but it doesn't help with the issue of element size.

My Code:

```css
*,
*:after,
*:before {
 -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
 box-sizing:border-box;
 -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
 font-smoothing:antialiased;
 text-rendering:optimizeLegibility;
}

a {
    text-decoration:none;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size:100%;
}

h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
    font-family: 'Rhodium Libre', serif;
}

header {
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#000;
    opacity:0.9;
    z-index:10000;
}

//desktop

/*logo*/


.logo-holder {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
    font-family: 'Rhodium Libre', serif;
    font-size:2.4em;
    background-color:white;
    width:200px;
}

    /* nav */
    
 .nav-holder {
     position:relative;
     float:right;
        width:500px;
    }
nav {
}

/*nav design*/

nav ul {
    display:inline;
}

nav ul li {
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    padding-top:4px;
    padding-bottom:4px;
    font-family:'Rhodium Libre', serif;
    font-size:1.35em;
}

nav ul li:hover, nav ul li:active {
    background:transparent;
    color:#5F8E14;
}
    
nav ul li a {
    padding-left:0.5em;
    color:#FFF;
}

nav ul li a:hover, nav ul li a:active {
    color:#5F8E14;
}

//sub menu

nav.sub {

}

nav.sub ul {
    display:inline;
}

nav.sub ul li {
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    padding-top:2px;
    padding-bottom:2px;
    font-family:'Rhodium Libre', serif;
    font-size:1.1em;
}

nav.sub ul li:hover, nav.sub ul li:active {
    background:transparent;
    color:transparent;
}

nav.sub a:hover, nav.sub ul li a:active {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <!-- header -->
    <header>
        <div class=logo-holder">
            why is nothing changing here?
        </div>
                            
        <div class="nav-holder">
            <nav>
                <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'header-menu' ) ); ?>
            </nav>
                            
            <nav class="sub">
                <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'sub-menu' ) ); ?>
            </nav>
        </div> <!--nav holder-->
    </header>
    <!-- /header -->
</body>
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You need to be more specific about what parts are not working and where.

Comment: The logo-holder class does absolutely nothing.  The font still runs the body, the font size doesn't change, the width inherits the header tag of 100% even though I have it set to 200px.

Comment: There's a typo in you code posting, it says 'class=logo-holder" ', missing the leading quotation mark.  Is that in the actual code?  If so, try fixing that and see if it helps.

Comment: I already found that error and it still doesn't work.  (I'm not sure why netbeans didn't pick it up)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`//` does not make a valid comment in CSS. `/* ... */` does.

Also,

```
   <div class=logo-holder">
```

is obviously lacking a `"`.

Comment: Thanks, the comment messed it up!